# How to make WebFilter urlPatterns with wildcard

Tags: spring-boot, interceptor

I have following type of URL

```
/demo/user/add
/demo/user/addAll
/test/customer/add
/test/customer/addAll
/dept/it/add
/dept/id/addAll
```

What is the correct way to write URL pattern on web filter which will cover all?
I have tried following none works

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns="/*/*/add")
@WebFilter(urlPatterns="/*add")
@WebFilter(urlPatterns="/*/add*")
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: Have you tried "/*"? Otherwise, I think you cannot.

Long answer:

I guess the answer is [here](https://docs.roguewave.com/hydraexpress/3.5.0/html/rwsfservletug/4-3.html):

> URL patterns use an extremely simple syntax. Every character in a
>   pattern must match the corresponding character in the URL path
>   exactly, with two exceptions. At the end of a pattern, /* matches any
>   sequence of characters from that point forward. The pattern
>   *.extension matches any file name ending with extension. No other wildcards are supported, and an asterisk at any other position in the
>   pattern is not a wildcard.